# Send All NON existent get request to a default page

Tags: php, variables, get, http-status-code-404, http-get

please be aware that I am very new to php.

okay I have a script.

that send variable pages to certain pages but only if the variable matches with an already preexisting page,

For example mysite.com/?varible123 and if varible123 exist it sends it to that page but if it doesn't exist then it sends it to the default page. which in my case my homepage "main" I dont want the nonexistent variable pages getting sent to my home page but rather a default just for those pages.

I want to modify the script to send all variables that dont exist to a default page other then the homepage.

and the home page to show when called.

so someone visit mysite.com they see the homepage, but if someone visit mypage.com/?nonexisitenpage they get sent to a default page that's not the home page.

the ? mark on the site has to stay there.

the code I have is

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['argv'][0];
if (!file_exists($page.".htm")){
 //check to make sure the file exists
 $page = "main";
 //include this page by default
}
if (strstr($page, ".")){ 
 //hack attempt
 $page = "main";
}
require_once($page.".htm");
//hard code extension to prevent getting hacked
//http://mysite.com/?lol will include lol.htm
?>
```

any help is apperciated.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code. Here's one important problem: what happens when somebody enters `?.something-starting-with-a-dot` as part of the url? `strstr($page,".")` will evaluate to zero which is the same as false and it will skip the next code block.

Answer (score 1):

you can use include. but each page has to have code to properly render it self within the other page, this will be the fastest to render.

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if (strstr($page, ".") !== false){ means . is there 
 //hack attempt
 $page = "main";
}
 //first check for hack

if (!file_exists($page.".htm")){
 //check to make sure the file exists
 $page = "main";

 //include this page by default
}
 include 'main.php'; //or main.html and return
   return;
//hard code extension to prevent getting hacked
//http://mysite.com/?lol will include lol.htm
?>
```

try this your self before opening it out to the world. maybe you should check for other spl characters or only allow a-z, underscore and dash as names.